# Google charts: Cannot read property 'color' of null

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I get this intermittent error with Google charts, perhaps once in every fives times the page with the charts is loaded.  I suspect that the issue is that I am using an array for the colours which is pulled from the server using jQuery Ajax.  The colours are held in the database as a serialised array.

The JS..

```
var $colours = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/charts_ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'userID='+$userID+'&action=getColours',
        success: function(response){
            $.each(response, function(i) {
                $colours[i] = response[i];
            });
        },
    });
});
```

PHP

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'getColours'){
    $userID = $_POST['userID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID = '$userID'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //get colour scheme being used from database
    $scheme = $row['colScheme'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM scheme WHERE schemeID = '$scheme'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $colours = $row['coloursArray'];
    $colour_scheme = unserialize($colours);
    echo json_encode($colour_scheme);
}
```

Back to the JS

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]}); 
google.setOnLoadCallback(targets);
function targets() {
    "use strict";
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ 
          ['Grade', 'Target', 'Interim Target', 'Actual'], 
          ['Grade 1',  70, 50, getPercent($grade1)], 
          ['Grade 2',  20, 40, getPercent($grade2)], 
          ['Grade 3',  10, 10, getPercent($grade3)] 
        ]); 
        var options = { 
          height: 360, 
          width:500, 
          title: 'Grade Targets', 
          colors: $colours, 
          hAxis: {title: 'Grades', titleTextStyle: {color: '#ffffff'}}, 
          vAxis: {title: 'Percentage', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}, format: '0'}, 
          fontName:"'Arial'", 
          backgroundColor: { fill: "none" } 
    }; 
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('targets')); 
    chart.draw(data, options); 
}
```

I have checked the JSON response from the AJAX call and it looks fine to me

```
["#32CCFE","#F68634","#713973","#B3C234","#E2DFCB","#C5F4FF","#C00","#FF5733","#FEB4FC"]
```

A bit of background, the reason why it pulls the colours from a database is that I have developed a site where users can create their own colour schemes for the charts and in some of the charts there is an unknown number of elements in the data array.

If using an array for the colours isn't the best solution, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who may encounter this problem, it seems that the charts were drawing before the ajax call had pulled the $colours array values from the database.

I resolved this by storing the values using this in the head of the page

```
<script>
  var $colours = <?php echo json_encode($colour_scheme); ?>;
</script>
```

That way the values had been saved in the array way before the charts were drawn.